# Capture only errors that are within namespace

Tags: javascript, sentry, raven

Is it possible to configure [raven-js](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-js) to ignore errors that are not within a defined namespace?

```
var Foo = Foo || {};

Foo.raiseWithinNamespace = function(){
   //bar is not defined, raises
   return bar;
}

function raiseOutOfNameSpace(){
   //bar is not defined, raises
   return bar;
}
```

So `Foo.raiseWithinNamespace` would be captured and `raiseOutOfNameSpace` would be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply replace each function in the namespace by a wrapper created by `Raven.wrap()`:

```
// Do not catch global errors
Raven.config(..., {collectWindowErrors: false}).install()

// Helper to catch exceptions for namespace
function catchInNamespace(ns)
{
  for (var key in ns)
  {
    if (ns.hasOwnProperty(key) && typeof ns[key] == "function")
      ns[key] = Raven.wrap(ns[key]);
  }
}

// Declaration of namespace Foo
var Foo = Foo || {};
Foo.func1 = ...;
Foo.func2 = ...;
catchInNamespace(Foo);

// Using namespace
Foo.func1();   // Any exceptions here are caught by Raven.js
```

Note that `collectWindowErrors: false` configuration option is required to ignore errors from other namespaces and global functions, without it Raven.js will catch all exceptions implicitly. This option has been [introduced in Raven.js 1.1.0](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-js/issues/91) but still isn't documented for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using class inheritance.

```
function capture_exception_iff(){};
//Errors will only be captured in Foo and A.
var Foo = Foo || new capture_exception_iff();
var A = A || new capture_exception_iff();
var B = B || {};


function Raven_capture_exception(e){
    if(this instanceof capture_exception_iff){
        Raven.captureException(e)
    }  
}

Foo.raiseWithinNamespace = function(){
   try {
      return bar;
   } catch(e) {
      Raven_capture_exception(e)
      //it will pass the if-statement 
      //Raven.captureException(e) will be called.
   }
 }

B.raiseWithinNamespace = function(){
   try {
      return bar;
   } catch(e) {
      Raven_capture_exception(e)
      //it will not pass the if-statement 
      //Raven.captureException(e) will not be called.
   }
 }

function raiseOutOfNameSpace(){
   try {
      return bar;
   } catch(e) {
      Raven_capture_exception(e)
      //it will not pass the if-statement
      //Raven.captureException(e) will not be called.
   }
}
```